# IDE with debugger able to view and manipulate python pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, ide, data-analysis, debugging

I'm conducting data science on medium-size datasets (~5000 entries with ~100 fields) that include input by humans. I am using the pandas python module developed by Wes McKinney.

I spend a lot of time bugfixing due to errors in the datasets. For example, someone has input ">23" in a field that should contain integers, or "xxx" in a field that should contain something more useful. Using Ipython notebook and a bit of data wrangling, these entries can be found quite quickly. However when the scripts get too large I migrate them into modules, upon which the dataframe is a local variable in a function. A debugger is then necessary to view or manipulate the data.

My questions:

Is there an IDE that correctly **displays** pandas dataframes?

- equivalent to the "view array" function of PyCharm (this works only for NumPy arrays)

Is there a debugger that allows **easy manipulation** of pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there an IDE that correctly displays pandas dataframes?**

PyCharm released version 2016.2 (a week after I posted this question!), which includes a pandas dataframe viewer.

[image: example right-click]

[image: example df view]

I still want to know if software exists that allows easy, ipython-like manipulation of such "local-variable" dataframes.

Comment: Mark, please accept your own answer. Doing so will help others who read this question  in future